# How can I recover a password for an Outlook 2007 account?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

How can I recover a password for an Outlook 2007 account?

Answer (score 4):

If the account still configured and working, you can use some "revealing password software" (like http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bullets_password_view.html) to show the password typed in back of the bullets\stars

Comment: Most anti-viruses vendors categorize it as malware, because it is used by some actual malware to access your passwords. (See [here](https://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/Encyclopedia/Entry.aspx?Name=HackTool:Win32/Mailpassview) for an example.) So you may have to convince your antivirus to let you run it.

Comment: Genius. Worked great to port an Outlook account that we had forgotten the password of.

Answer (score 3):

If this is an email related account then you'll need to work with your email provider/host to perform a password reset for your account.  Most providers will provide this functionality to you through their hosting control panel.  Then you go into your account settings in Outlook and update the settings with your new account.

Outlook doesn't have accounts, per se.  It uses the account information from whatever service providers you are using in order to log into those services.

If you are talking about a password that you've set on an archive file / personal folders file (ie- .pst file) then this will be a bit harder.  That password is set by you.  You'll have to get one of the many tools available that will recover Outlook 2007 passwords.